# Jailbreak check method, apple will approve this?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

In my app i need to check sometimes if the running device is a jailbreak device or not. This is the most complete method i have found:

```
BOOL Jail=NO;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"] ||
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/bin/bash"] ||
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/sbin/sshd"] ||
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/etc/apt"] ||
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt/"] ||
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"]])  {
  Jail= YES;
}

FILE *f = NULL ;
if ((f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r")) ||
   (f = fopen("/Applications/Cydia.app", "r")) ||
   (f = fopen("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib", "r")) ||
   (f = fopen("/usr/sbin/sshd", "r")) ||
   (f = fopen("/etc/apt", "r")))  {
  fclose(f);
  Jail= YES;
}
fclose(f);

NSError *error;
NSString *stringToBeWritten = @"This is a test.";
[stringToBeWritten writeToFile:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" error:nil];
if(error == nil)
{
  Jail= YES;
}
```

What i haven't found, it's a clear answer to the question: "Apple will approve this code?" , in guidelines i can read:

```
"Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected".
```

However it's clear that i'm trying to write or read only to check if the device is jailbroken... So there's someone that have successfully submitted this code to apple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect that an iOS app is running on a jailbroken phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

Comment: Read the comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26712383/329801

Comment: thank's i haven't read this... Anyway it's only a comment, of only one person and i don't know if that user have really submit the code or if he only suppose that the code will be accepted

Comment: you should use the _Receipt Validation_ procedure instead. you can find more information about that on the official [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1), and I would recommend watch the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) as well – it is much better than reading files outside of your app's sandbox, which pretty much ends up with rejection.

Comment: Did you app pass review? We are intersted in this too

Comment: the app is still under development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe.

Many developer's have been rejected for including jailbreak checking, and many have not. If you submit with a jailbreak check, you should **NOT** expect to be approved (although you may get through the review process this time).

- [App with jailbreak detection rejected by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753192/app-with-jailbreak-detection-rejected-by-apple)
- https://github.com/sat2eesh/ios-jailBroken/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

This is the code of a submitted app

```
BOOL bash = NO;

FILE *f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r");
if (f != NULL)
{
    bash = YES;
}
fclose(f);

return bash;
```

So, I believe your code will be accepted too