# std::thread::detach raising a system_error No Such Process

Tags: c++, ios, multithreading

Our iOS crash reporter tool list many exceptions raised by std::thread::detach:

> ```
> Fatal Exception: std::__1::system_error
> thread::detach failed: No such process
> ```

As our implementation doesn't check if the std::thread instance is joinable, we thought the issue could be that the thread is already terminated so we tried to reproduce the issue with a code such as

```
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    std::thread noneThread([]() {
        int a = 3;
    });
    assert(noneThread.joinable());
    noneThread.detach();
}
```

This code works fine on iOS, MacOS X and Ubuntu as the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) explains it :

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined
>   is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore
>   joinable.

Checking joinable before invoking detach may avoid the exception but that doesn't answer the following question

- What could be the origin of this exception?

Comment: Can you produce your actual code?  I see nothing in this example that would cause an exception to be raised even if the `assert` call was removed.

Comment: No I can not produce/disclose the actual code.

Comment: any chance you calling fork() in your process ?

Comment: [Fork is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31071971/230825) on iOS.